# sqlalchemy ORM: joining tables from different databases in one query

Tags: python, sql-server, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and orm and have had some issues joining tables from different databases.

Using pandas I can query multiple databases on the same server using something like this:

```
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("some_server")
    df = pd.read_sql_query("""
             select top 10 t1.*
             from db1.dbo.table1 t1
             inner join db2.dbo.table2 t2 
                 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
             """,
             engine
         )
```

I would now like to do a similar operation using sqlalchemy's orm. 
Now say that I have obtained the metadata information from the databases so that I have T1 and T2 as Tables. If I now start a session and create a query:

```
    Session = sessionmaker()
    Session.configure(binds={
        T1: create_engine("server_db1"),
        T2: create_engine("server_db2")
    }
    session = Session()
    q = (session.query(T1)
                .join(T2, T1.c.user_id == T2.c.user_id)
                .limit(10)
    )
```

The resulting SQL statement generated from this query will not take into account the database names specified in the engines, and therefore I will have the following query:

```
             select top 10 t1.*
             from dbo.table1 t1
             inner join dbo.table2 t2 
                 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Which, when I want to retrieve the results using one() or all() results in an Invalid object name error on table2 since table2 only exists in db2.

So my questions are:

1. Am I creating the engines, binds, sessions correct?
2. If it isn't possible to query tables from different databases, is it possible to add databasename to the querystring so that I still can use the querystring in e.g. a pandas.read_sql_query?
3. Can I add some attribute to the tables that make it possible for the query to make use of full db.schema.table name?

Any words of advice from people with more experience with sqlalchemy and orm would also be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot query across binds. A query is sent to a single connection, so while you can use a single session to query multiple databases, you cannot do it in one query. You can on the other hand include the (multi part) schema of a table in your definitions (and models) and through that emit queries that join across databases, if your server is suitably configured – as it seems to be.

Comment: Thank you both!!! It worked wonders.